# Disable system wide Ctrl+Click in OS X

Tags: macos, mouse

I'm used to navigating through my code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click. In OS X this function still works in my IDE, but it opens a context menu as well, which is very annoying!

I've done lots of Googling and didn't manage to find any answers that would let me disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click system-wide in OS X 10.6.7. All the answers that I was able to find refer to Fusion and VMware.

I have a proper mouse with two buttons, I never used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click and cannot see the use case for it. Could someone please tell me how to disable it?

Comment: I don't think you can disable Control-Clicks. Can you maybe configure your editor/code browser to use Command-Clicks?

Comment: Yes, I could, but I don't want to. I think there should be a way to do it (sudo edit some prefs or something).

Comment: You can remap the Ctrl key but this is system-wide then.

Comment: Again a possibility, but I'd rather have the Ctrl key behave as a Ctrl key. I cannot believe disabling this "feature" is so difficult!

Answer (score 5):

You can map control+click to command+click globally with [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). Put the following in your private.xml:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Control+LeftClick Command+LeftClick</name>
        <appendix>Control+LeftClick Command+LeftClick</appendix>
        <identifier>control_click_to_command_click</identifier>
        <autogen>--PointingButtonToPointingButton-- PointingButton::LEFT, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, PointingButton::LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

This will cause any <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click you type to be seen by the system as <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click.  That will prevent the contextual menu (since you won't actually be producing a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>).  You'll still need to change your IDE settings, but this way you can keep the muscle-memory for the shortcut.

Comment: This one worked great. I think the app is called Karabiner now. There's a button to open private.xml in its Misc & Uninstall tab. After editing the file reload it (Reload XML button on Change Key tab) and enable remapping (same tab)

Comment: Thank you @OlegMikheev, but this disables the short cut when another app wants to use it

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click at a system-wide level.
You have two options: use <kbd>Command</kbd>+Click which is the *de facto* standard in all the Mac IDEs (which would be my suggestion, since going against such a well-established OS convention brings more headaches than it's worth), or configure your IDE to disable the shortcut: as you have noticed, remote desktop and virtualization environments offer the possibility.

Comment: I agree that using cmd+Click is the best potential solution. I just wanted to know if it's possible to disable it altogether and it seems a shame it isn't.

The reason why I wanted to use Ctrl+Click instead is because most of the time I work on Windows and only every so often work on a Mac. With Windows keyboard plugged in I want the transition between OSs to be as seamless as possible.

Comment: @Artur what do you do about copy/paste as you have the same cmd control key issue?

Comment: @Mark I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and it remaps these keys for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following @statop's idea I used [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements) and remapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd>.

To do that copy the mapping JSON snippet shown below to `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/foo.json`:

```
{
  "title": "Ctrl+LClick to Cmd+LClick",
  "rules": [
    {   
      "description": "Ctrl+LClick to Cmd+LClick",
      "manipulators": [
        {   
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "pointing_button": "button1",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_control"
              ],  
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]   
            }   
          },  
          "to": [
            {   
              "pointing_button": "button1",
              "modifiers": [
                "left_command"
              ]   
            }   
          ]   
        }   
      ]   
    }   
  ]
}
```

then in Karabiner go to:

```
Preferences... > Complex modifications > Add Rule
```

and you should see `Ctrl+LClick to Cmd+LClick` in the list. Enable the rule. Now configure your IDE to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> where you would normally use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd>.

Using this opportunity I also swapped round <kbd>Fn</kbd> with <kbd>^</kbd>, as on my Mac <kbd>Fn</kbd> is where <kbd>^</kbd> should be. To do that in Karabiner go to:

```
Preferences... > Simple modifications > Add item
```

and create two mappings:

- from `fn` to `left_control`, and
- from `left_control` to `fn`.

Carry on remapping and soon enough your Mac will become a usable machine!