# Disable system-wide ctrl-click as right-click in Mavericks

Tags: keyboard, macos, mouse

Disabling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click as right-click is useful because:

1. Many web app rely on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click (typically for multiple selection).
2. There is little use for this combo (mice have 2+ buttons and trackpad emulate right-click with two-finger click or clicking in the right zone).

Can it be done in OS X Mavericks?

This question has been [asked before for Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/disable-system-wide-ctrlclick-in-os-x) and answered negatively (i.e. a third party utility is needed). Has this improved for Mavericks?

Comment: Note: for the first point it's cleary a design flaw, since on OSX multiple selection if achieve with Cmd.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no system supported method for disabling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click from functioning as a secondary click in Mavericks.

You can use Karabiner Elements to remap "Control+LeftClick to LeftClick," which essentially disables this behavior system-wide.

---

**Step 1:**

Install Karabiner Elements:
https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

---

**Step 2:**

When you then go to open Karabiner Elements, it will have a couple security issues you need to resolve.

The first will be to allow the installation of a kernel extension:
[image: Karabiner Elements kernel extension request]

The second will be to allow input monitoring:
[image: Karabiner Elements input monitoring request]

---

**Step 3:**

Once those security issues are handled, you then need to add a complex modification. Visit:
https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#control_lclick_to_lclick

Then click `Import` on the `Disable Ctrl Click` modification:
[image: Disable Ctrl Click modification]

This will add the complex modification to Karabiner Elements and enable the functionality:
[image: Karabiner Elements complex modifications]

---

**Addendum:**

However, I don't know of any web apps (and certainly not most or many) which don't recognize and respect <kbd>Command</kbd>+LeftClick as a way to multi-select. That is the standard for macOS.

Comment: this is not the best choice if you need to use the CTRL+click for some other action, this will completly remap it, so you can;t use it elsewhere

Comment: Also `Karabiner-EventViewer` will help you debug keys (in my case a bug made the Cmd key always on)

Comment: Karabiner-Elements-11.6.0 on High Sierra 10.13.3 does not have any choice starting with `control` in the "Simple Modifications" tab (the first one). Anybody with an idea how to fix Ctrl key with this combo?

Comment: This application has changed, you'll need to import this "Complex Modification" rule https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#control_lclick_to_lclick

Comment: Did that "Complex Modification" rule "ctrl+left click to click" imported, but it doesn't seem to work, I still got the context menu poped up

Comment: @GelinLuo I updated the answer to include the updated instructions

Comment: It's important to note that if you're using a mouse, you must go to Karabiner-Elements Preferences -> Devices -> enable the mouse.

Comment: it seems that there is a bug in Karabiner that prevents the modification from working on a trackpad, see https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2157

Comment: This seems to work, but only for a single click. I need this change for click and hold (to play minecraft lol). Can someone explain how to do that?

Comment: @Malaber You shouldn't need to do this for Minecraft. macOS handles two-button mice just fine, and has options for the Magic Mouse and the built-in touchpads to use left/right side clicks or two-finger clicks: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/right-click-mh35853/mac

Answer (score 28):

In my VMWare Windows 7 guest, I have found (after reading this post) that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+LeftClick works the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+LeftClick would in a hardware Windows machine.

Comment: How do i turn this feature off lol

Answer (score 6):

Try the <kbd>right option key</kbd>+click

This works for me using parallels with Windows 8.1, I haven’t personally come across web apps that use this, so I can't test this.

Right click actually emulates <kbd>control</kbd>+click due to the history of apple sticking with a single button mouse for so long, thus the context menu used the <kbd>control</kbd> click method, plus Mac OS X doesn’t have a context key on the keyboard like Windows Keyboards (located on the right side of the main keyboard, in-between the <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> (<kbd>alt</kbd> GR) or <kbd>windows</kbd> keys).

Answer (score 5):

I found that I can use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd> in lieu of <kbd>Control</kbd> when using online Flash training applications (I'm using 10.8.5 Mountain Lion).

Answer (score 5):

BetterTouchTool allows ctrl-click remapping.
There is an example of ctrl-click to alt-space remapping for IDEA.
[image]

Comment: Ooh, this is perfect - and a useful tip for PyCharm too - alt+Space is much more useful and the silly right click menu.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+LeftClick, [recommended](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118276/disable-system-wide-ctrl-click-as-right-click-in-mavericks/#168318) by [mvreijn](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/110514/mvreijn) for VMware Windows 7 guests, works quite nicely in Citrix connections to Windows 7 machines.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Linux VM in VMware Fusion for development, where I want to ctrl-click to navigate to method definitions.

In the VM settings for "keyboard and mouse", choose the "Mac" profile instead of the Standard profile. This disables the OSX stubbornness for the respective VM.

Comment: I've been going around this for a few months. Why is the "Mac" profile the one that is actually working like it should in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences->Keyboard->Modifier Keys, you can change the function of the keys. If you switch cmd with ctrl, ctrl will work with applications as ctrl without the right click.

Answer (score -3):

just go to Accessibility > Keyboard > Open Keyboard Preferences... > Modifier Keys > Contro (^) Key > No Action

click ok then youre done!

Comment: What?! You can't mean that.

Comment: Not a good idea—this just disables the Control key entirely.

Comment: this is no solution... you must be joking.. this way you can;t use the ctrl key for any other shortcut !